# How to apply a function to the parameter of another function?

Tags: function, haskell, parameters

I have defined the following functions:

```
isOk :: Group -> Bool
//some condition

filterGroup :: [Group] -> [Group]
filterGroup g = filter isOk g

getGroupNb :: Group -> NoGroupe
getGroupNb (Group _ noGroupe _ _ _) = noGroupe

nbGroup :: [Group] -> [NoGroupe]
nbGroup groupX = map getGroupNb groupX
```

I want to apply the function `filterGroup` to the `[Group]` that is passed as a parameter to the last function `nbGroup`. I would like something like that, for the last function:

```
nbGroup :: [Group] -> [NoGroupe]
nbGroup where [Group] = filterGroup[Group]
nbGroup groupX = map getGroupNb groupX
```

How can I apply a function to a parameter of another function?

Comment: Please do *not* add tags in titles. A question title should be an *english sentence* **not** something like `Tag1 - (Tag2) [Tag3] - apply function`. We have tag fields for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just apply the filter directly:

```
nbGroup :: [Group] -> [NoGroupe]
nbGroup groupX = map getGroupNb (filterGroup groupX)
```